# DS18B20 temp sensor IC

Tags: temperature, 1-wire, sensing

DS18B20 temp sensor IC `Dq` pin is connected to `PSEN` of controller in my application.

But in datasheet its mentioned that its connected to I/O port.

And second doubt is how I/O port senses temp? It should be connected to `ADC` pin of controller.

Comment: The DS18B20 doesn't need to be connected to an ADC, as it works digitally. You probably want to search about how to implement 1-Wire using your microcontroller (I'd guess it's an 8051 because you said `PSEN`).

Comment: Can we connect Dq to PSEN~ (PSEN bar)?  PSEN~ is I/O pin?

Comment: I don't know (never used the 8051) but from searching around, PSEN is not an I/O pin, therefore you can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DS18B20 is a digital Thermometer, thus you will not need any ADC. DS18B20 communicates with microcontroller through 1-wire protocol. You can also implement 1-wire protocol using GPIO. see below link for more details on software implementation of 1-wire protocol
http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/126